# The "concreteness preorder" on categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

A category is called **concrete** if it is equipped with faithful functor to $\mathrm{Set}$.  Let us say a category $C$ **can be made concrete** if there *exists* a faithful functor $F \colon C \to \mathrm{Set}$.

A famous result of Freyd, from his paper [Homotopy is not concrete](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6.pdf), gives an example of a category that cannot be made concrete.   Let $\mathcal{T}$ be any category with

- some class of pointed topological spaces containing all finite-dimensional CW complexes as objects

and

- homotopy classes of basepoint-preserving continuous maps as morphisms.

Then Freyd showed $\mathcal{T}$ cannot be made concrete.

I believe one can deduce from this that the usual [homotopy category of topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category#The_homotopy_category,_following_Quillen), $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathrm{Top})$, cannot be made concrete.

More generally, given categories $C$ and $D$, write $C \le D$ if there exists a faithful functor from $C$ to $D$.  This gives a preorder on categories which I'll call the **concreteness preorder**.

Freyd's result shows $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathrm{Top}) \nleq \mathrm{Set}$.   On the other hand, $\mathrm{Set} \le \mathrm{Ho}(\mathrm{Top})$ thanks to the functor sending any set to the corresponding discrete space and any function to the corresponding equivalence class of maps.

So, we can say $\mathrm{Set} \lt \mathrm{Ho}(\mathrm{Top})$ in the concreteness preorder.

This is a rather simple-minded but precise way of saying that set theory can be embedded in homotopy theory but not conversely.

My question is simply, **what other nice results are known about the concreteness preorder on categories?**

For example are there some well-studied categories that are very high in this order?   I imagine the homotopy category of $(\infty,n+1)$-categories is higher up than homotopy category of $(\infty,n)$-categories.

Comment: you can look at : https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00303 but as far as I know, not much more is known

Comment: @JohnBaez: see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270904/faithful-earths-of-categories It is a nice Christmas present that you are entering a similar circle of thought!

Comment: @JohnBaez: Ivan recently gave a talk at MPIM on this subject: http://www.math.muni.cz/~diliberti/Talk/Golem.pdf and has a section in it on his research plan (§1 of http://www.math.muni.cz/~diliberti/memoir.pdf )

Comment: It seems likely to me that there is a functors  from $(\infty,n)$-categories to spaces faithful on the homotopy categories. For example sending a category to the disjoint union of its spaces of $k$-cells for $k \leqslant n$,

Comment: To clarify: the question only makes sense if "category" means "locally small category". Kucera [showed](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(71)90004-1) that every category is a localization of a concrete category. Velebilova [gave](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1992-1079899-X) conditions under which a localization of a concrete category is concrete. Perhaps thinking about her conditions could give a stratification of categories by concreteness. Freyd also gave necessary and sufficient conditions for concreteness in "On the concreteness of certain categories".

Comment: There is also work by Pultr and Trnkova on the preorder on categories given by _full_ embeddability. Keyword "universal categories".

Comment: People in semigroup theory have looked at the related pre-order $C\prec D$ of $C$ is a quotient of a category $C'$ with a faithful functor to $D$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg can you link something?!

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404987901071

Comment: @FoscoLoregian - thanks!  Ivan di Liberti's talk ends with the question: is there any (locally small) category that does not admit a faithful functor to the homotopy category of CW complexes?   It's amazing that this is, or at least was, an open question.  If anyone solves it,  I hope they let me know!